# how to do Time Based splitting of Amazon fine food reviews dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to do time-based splitting on Amazon food reviews dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/snap/amazon-fine-food-reviews ). But I don't understand the time format and also how can I divide the data after it is sorted according to time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those dates are on timestamp. try to convert them useing:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.fromtimestamp(1540574790)
```

where "1540574790" is a moment ago for example.. for more, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time